# mongo-java-driver how to create mongo's user on doesn't exists database yet

Tags: mongodb

Can i create the first user on mongodb by mongo-java-driver? i tried but got this error.

```
com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "localhost:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "Authentication failed." , "code" : 18 , "codeName" : "AuthenticationFailed"}
```

Comment: Yes, you can. Follow instructions in documentation for setting up auth and substitude mongo shell instructions for driver commands.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I tried create user on not exists database yet, with mongodb was started with --auth option but couldn't.